# How to conditionally change some values if the rows in some columns are the same?

Tags: python, iteration, data-manipulation

I am working on a big dataset with addresses, electricity consumption, cadastral data etc. My task is to adjust the data in the following way: If the 'ADDRESS' is the same in certain rows then calculate the ratio of the corresponding 'Total Area' and change the values of the electricity consumption (columns of months) taking into consideration the previously calculated ratio of the areas.
In my head I have the idea to iterate over the address column and if the value as the same as the previous one, make the condition to change the electricity consumption value basing on the ratio of areas.
I just started my journey with Python Pandas and coding so I would really appreciate any help.

[Dataset that I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44zex.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Alternatively, you can format it as a table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.